# php header: how to include nofollow in a location command

Tags: php, header, location, nofollow

I am using: `header("Location: https://www.link.com");` but I want to be able to specify a no-follow in it. In another post someone explained to use `header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow", true);`. But how do I combine them? I tried `header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow; Location: https://www.link.com"), true);` but it did not work. Does anyone know the correct syntax? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You call it multiple times:

```php
header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow");
header("Location: https://www.example.com");
```